# MYSQL: sum mysql rows by specific character and add the results into an equation

Tags: mysql

Please I have a single table where it has 3 columns like the below:

```
 id   value  type
-----------------
1001  -10     L
1002   20     W
1003  -21     L
1004  -29     L
1005   12     D
1006   19     W
1007   18     W
1008   15     W
1009   88     O
1010   11     N
1011   44     S
```

I want to count values of each type sum them up after that in this way:

L + W + D + O = TOTAL (To have a clear total of all the specified types.)

Comment: So the answer's 9, right?

Comment: The max I could do is a totalValue for each type or all values with order which I don't want this way.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

SELECT SUM(total) from  (
    select sum(`value`) as total from `table` where `type` = 'L'
    union all
    select sum(`value`) as total from `table` where `type` = 'W'
    union all
    select sum(`value`) as total from `table` where `type` = 'D'
    union all
    select sum(`value`) as total from `table` where `type` = 'O'
    )a

Thanks for all who took time to review my question. I figured it out my way and posted the answer to help anyone who had the same question or would have the same in the future. Thanks for all the answers as well :)).